# Why is fluoride good for your teeth?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, aqueous-solution

The main component of tooth enamel is calcium hydroxyapatite. I know fluoride ions can replace hydroxide ions in the enamel matrix, slowing the rate of enamel demineralization. Why does hydrofluoric acid dissolved in water have no adverse health effects on other areas of the mouth? I suspect that its because the fluoride is in low enough concentrations to help your teeth and not harm the gums.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/2395/why-is-tin-ii-fluoride-more-effective-in-turning-apatite-into-fluorapatite

Comment: > Why does hydrofluoric acid dissolved in water have no adverse health effects on other areas of the mouth?  || It definitely does. Fluoride in significant concentrations can cause sedimentation of calcium, which may lead to very bad things (tm) happening to heart. However 1) fluoride is NOT used as a fluoric acid and 2) it is used in very low concentrations.